# Why doesn't SKCameraNode center if aspect mismatch? Bug?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Is there a bug in `SKCameraNode` when used with `.AspectFill` on devices where the aspect ratio of the `SKScene` does not match that of the devices view?

I have a [minimal demo](https://github.com/sarah-j-smith/fix-skcamera) of the issue I see: an `SKScene` created in an SKS file, to be 768w x 1024h, filled with an image (also 768w x 1024h).  It's loaded with `.AspectFill`.  An `SKLabel` is positioned in the middle of the scene programmatically.  The demo is simply the out-of-the-box iOS template for a SpriteKit game, with a background image added.

An iPad in Portrait (so 768w x 1024h) displays this fine. An iPhone 6+ in Portrait (414w x 736h) displays fine.  An iPhone 5S (320w x 568h) displays fine.

If I **add a camera** to the scene, position it in the middle by setting its coordinates to `(384, 512)` in the SKS file and set the scene to use it, the iPad is fine but now the iPhones (and any other device with a aspect ratio other than 3:4) does NOT work.  It displays the right-hand side of the scene.  It is not centered.  Screen shot from the iPhone below.

[image: Image not centered if SKScene ratio doesn't match device]

The camera being in the middle of the scene, should ALWAYS work.

I am currently using a work-around.  When you use `.AspectFill` the sides of the scene are cropped by an amount - let's call it `cropAmount` - to fit on the narrower screen.  The work-around is to move the camera left, so it is off-center by `cropAmount`, then the scene displays correctly.

The background image here is an @3x of a 768w x 1024h background for my game.  I've put in green the `cropAmount` corresponding to the SKView for 9:16, and in red the scene bounds.  Given the camera is set in the middle of the scene, *same as the label* and the pink dot in the middle of the image, why is the center of the view not also there?

If this is a bug, and I leave in my "fix" where I offset the camera by `cropAmount`, later updates could break production code running on devices.

Also I am not using `.ResizeFill` as it doesn't fix the camera node issue, and would also mean that the assets are incorrectly sized and positioned in the scene for the thousands of lines of code and dozens of SKS files I already have over 6 months of work.

**Question has been edited.  Originally I had my "fix" added as an extension but this just caused confusion so I have removed it.**

Comment: Are you using Auto layouts?  From a quick glance,  you are taking the middle of the view, not the middle of the scene,  Auto layout is going to resize your view, but since you are using aspect fill,  I do not see your scene resizing, thus your numbers will be off

Comment: Auto layouts are enabled.  The minimal test project was just "click new Swift game".  The only code I touched was in GameScene.

Comment: In the screen shot above, I haven't taken the center of the view: that's what  you get out of the box, with an SKCameraNode set in the SKS file to be at `(384,512)`, which is the center of the scene.  You're right that the scene does not resize: it stays the same in SKScene co-ordinates, as 768x1024.  `SKCameraNode` is in scene co-ordinates, not UIView space.

Comment: I wouldn't have said it if you weren't doing it, look at your code `let displayedWidth = viewSize.width / viewScale` , displayRect returns `CGRect(x: xMargin, y: yMargin, width: displayedWidth, height: displayedHeight)`   midpoint is `let sceneRect = displayedRect;
            return CGPoint(x: sceneRect.origin.x + sceneRect.width/2, y: sceneRect.origin.y + sceneRect.height/2)`  so yes, you are using the view

Comment: Change `.AspectFill` to `.ResizeFill` in your view controller.

Comment: Hi @0x141E -  Changing it to `.ResizeFill` does not solve the problem.  I have a screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/khoE8   Also Apple supplies `.AspectFill` in its template, its used by Ray Wenderlich in the book iOS Games, and documented heavily.  Its worked fine, right up until I used it with SKCameraNode.